# How to show the image of the fits file what I want to see among several fits file in astrodrizzle

Tags: observational-astronomy, drizzle, tweakreg

Before running astrodrizzle(a library that can align the fits file images), I runned "tweakreg" to update fits header.

I used the bullet cluster data(ACS/WFC's five filters and 42 exposures), In tweakreg, forty-two "sci1" extensions is matched the reference file, but five "sci2" extension is not matched with the reference file.

I know this fact from "*fit.match" file.
But I want to see the file that are not matched with the reference file by using checking the result of astrodrizzle.

But I don't know how to mark the specific exposure that I want to see.

i.e., How to draw this exposure only as another color?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done just using ds9 tool.

If I set the red color as drizzled image, and blue and green color as 'CHIP1 and CHIP2' of the image what I want to check, I can check the coverage of the image in drizzled image!